# method with custom return type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

how do I create a method with custom return type??

I basically want to return **"View Controller"** and further use the same method as IBAction in interface builder and point to a button...

I basically want to call below method or create a custom method which could be called using a button... it there a way ?

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 

{ 
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController labelContents]];
    if(currentIndex == self.modelArray.count-1)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    contentViewController.labelContents = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];
return contentViewController; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a method and connect it to the button

.h

```
 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController ;     
 -(IBAction)myMethod; //connect this to your button
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)myMethod
 {
    //assuming you want you want to push to returned view controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self pageViewController:viewController viewControllerAfterViewController:viewController2] animated:YES];        
 }

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
 { 
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController labelContents]];
    if(currentIndex == self.modelArray.count-1)
    {
    return nil;
    }

 ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
 contentViewController.labelContents = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];
 return contentViewController; 
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Actions don't return anything (where would they return it to?).

Comment: hi @jrturton - upon doing so it says **use of undeclared identifier view controller** I am sure it will say the same for viewcontroller2 as well...
for quick reference .. pageviewcontroller is an instance of UIPAGEVIEWCONTROLLER and I have 4 class files
1.  ViewController.h     2.  ViewController.m   3.  ContentViewController.h   4.   ContentViewController.m

Comment: what is **ViewController** and **Viewcontroller2** in MyMethod stands for ??

Comment: @Abhinav they are the arguments you pass to the method. in your case, `UIPageViewController *viewcontroller` or `UIPageViewController *anyNameYouWant` and `UIViewController *viewcontroller2` or `UIViewController *anyNameYouWant`

Answer (score -2):

IBAction is simply used as a hint, it is not "binding". This means you can do what you want in one of a few ways:

1. Programmatically. Set the action of the button in something like viewDidLoad, using a @selector(yourActionMethod:)
2. "trick" xcode; setup the method as IBAction first, then do the connection with drag & drop, then change the declaration/implementation of the method. It'll work.

Comment: in what Xcode version the suggestion number 2 here can work? tried it on 4.2.1 but the connection of my button is lost.

Comment: You connection only *appears* to be lost. I bet it's still there. I tested on Xcode 4.3.3, but I don't think it's new. It will take away the little-circle indicators, but the storyboard still has the connection archived in it.

Comment: I am new to objective c -- should I write the method as following -(ViewConroller )turnpage:(id)sender; 

when I do this it gives warning... **conflicting return type void Vs viewcontrller **

Comment: @Abhinav it should be  -(ViewConroller *)turnpage:(id)sender;  , you  missed the pointer *

Comment: also to give you a better idea , I am doing making a ibook like application and not using stroryboard.. and I want to jump between pages... and to jump the return type should be of type **ViewContrller**

Comment: @janusfidel - My mistake that was a typo error, it still says the same :-(

Comment: @ctrahey could it be because im not using storyboard? I followed what you suggested here. button is responding at first, after I changed the return type, no more respond.

Comment: @janusfidel Are you changing the prototype and the implementation? I'm not sure if it will behave the same from XIB as from storyboard... it's possible that's the difference.

Comment: @Abhinav I think it's because you have not changed the return type in the `@interface` as well as the `@implementation`. Also, you might consider rethinking your design... usually you will not *ever* need to return a VC from an IBAction method. At the very least, have two methods, and call your VC_returning one from your IBAction one...

Comment: @ctrahey - I basically want to call below method or create a custom method which could be called using a button... it there a way ?

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    return contentViewController;
}

Comment: @Abhinav instead of making the comment chain long, please add your comments to the original post :) so others can easily see it and they have clearer view of what you want to accomplish

Comment: IBAction evaluates to `void`, you can't just swap in another type - where does the return value go?